# Orthogonality of stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, stochastic-matrices

Given a column stochastic matrix $P$, I wanted to give a relation between $\|P\|$ and orthogonality of $P$.

One simple way to think about how close $P$ is to being orthogonal is $\|P^{\top}P - I\|$. Then, I simply went ahead and wrote:
$$\|P\| \leq \sqrt{\|P^{\top}P - I\| + \|I\|}$$

First of all, does the above make sense? Secondly, I am not utilizing the fact that $P$ is stochastic, are there ways to get any better relationship than the one given above? Are there any measures defined for stochastic matrices (in literature) that measure how close a matrix is to being orthogonal?

P.S. All norms are Frobenius norms.

Comment: For the loss of orthogonality, you might find some interesting pointers in Section 4 [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.2899).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thanks for the pointer! Theorem 4.1 looks very very useful!!